# Как отсеять часть людей с определённой ролью [без if]? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Нужно отсеять людей с определённой ролью, чтобы они при рандомном выбирании людей они не выбирались [логично].
Код:

```
    winnerslist = []
    num = 0 
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(settings['role_ID'])
    for i in range(amount):
        winmember = [member for member in ctx.guild.members if member.bot == False] #Спасибо denisnumb <3
        winners = rrandom.choice(winmember)
        if role in winners.roles:
            pass
        else:
            num += 1
            print(str(num) + f" выбран. [Из {amount}]")
            await winners.add_roles(role)
            winnerslist.append(winners.mention)

    await ctx.send('\n'.join(str(x) for x in winnerslist))
```

Вот эта часть кода отсеивает людей с ролью, НО теряется общее кол-во людей.

```
if role in winners.roles:
    pass
```

Вот что выходит у нас:
[image: log]

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял задачу, можно создать список(whitelist) всех людей, и из него удалить тех кого надо "отсеять" и уже из этого списка рандомно выбирать людей.

Comment: надо отсеять людей на стадии выбора, как сделано в winmember, только я не знаю как это сделать с ролью